# Hybris custom table getting overwritten each time

Tags: deployment, sap-commerce-cloud

I have defined a custom item type in my custom extension. Its using default hsql db. It supposed to save all the transaction related metadata for each order placed. But, each time I place an order from storefront, it replaces the previously stored data and thus at the end, I only have one row of data left in the table.
I tried looking in hybris wiki but could not find any property that needs to be set for this.

This is a item type definition in my extension's item.xml file

```
<itemtype code="PaymetricITransHeaderObject2"
              extends="GenericItem"
              autocreate="true"
              generate="true">

        <deployment table="ITransPayLoadTable2" typecode="11011"/>

        <attributes>
             <attribute qualifier="trans_id" type="java.lang.String">
             <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="false" unique="true"/>
             <persistence type="property" />
             </attribute>
             <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="payload" type="java.lang.String">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="false"/>
                <persistence type="property">
                <columntype>
                        <value>varchar(8K)</value>
                </columntype>
                </persistence>
            </attribute>

        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
```

and this is a java code that saves this type

```
 public PaymetricITransHeaderObject2Model iTransactionHeaderObj = new PaymetricITransHeaderObject2Model();
 iTransactionHeaderObj.setTrans_id("1234");
 iTransactionHeaderObj.setPayload("some long string....");
 Transaction tx = Transaction.current();
try
    {
        tx = Transaction.current();
        tx.begin();

        modelService.save(iTransactionHeaderObj);

        tx.commit();

    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        if (null != tx)
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }


        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Any recommendations are appreciated !!
I am using Hybris 6.4 version

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<attribute qualifier="trans_id" type="java.lang.String">
         <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="false" unique="true"/>
         <persistence type="property" />
</attribute>
```

Here you have declared `trans_id` as unique (`unique="true"`), so make sure each time you set unique trans_id in your class.

like:

```
 iTransactionHeaderObj.setTrans_id(transGenerator.generate().toString());
```

---

Have a look at [Persistent Key Generation](https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/8c73dbae866910148f6889b98a54e067.html) to generate a unique number

**local.properties**

```
keygen.serialNumber.code.name=serial_number_code
keygen.serialNumber.code.digits=10
keygen.serialNumber.code.start=7000000000
keygen.serialNumber.code.type=numeric
keygen.serialNumber.code.template=$
```

***spring.xml**

```
<bean id="serialNumberCodeGenerator" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.keygenerator.impl.PersistentKeyGenerator">
    <property name="key" value="${keygen.serialNumber.code.name}"/>
    <property name="digits" value="${keygen.serialNumber.code.digits}"/>
    <property name="start" value="${keygen.serialNumber.code.start}"/>
    <property name="type" value="${keygen.serialNumber.code.type}"/>
    <property name="template" value="${keygen.serialNumber.code.template}"/>
</bean>
```

**.java**

```
@Resource
private KeyGenerator serialNumberCodeGenerator;

String serialNumber = serialNumberCodeGenerator.generate().toString();
```

Comment: @Sanket - I am glad, this helps you. what exactly causing the issue and how you solve it.